# Promise.all and then (js)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I'm kind of new with the whole promise thing so I might be doing something really wrong. If anyone can enlighten me, all advices/informations are welcome.

So here's the code of what I'm trying to accomplish (simplified and absolutly not optimal for understanding purpose):

```
// Get data from webservice    
$scope.sendGet(id, option).then(function (response){
        // Fill the model
        $scope.model[option] = response.data;
    }).then(function(){
        if(option == $scope.PROFILES){

                var p1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    $scope.getX1($scope.model[option][0][0].id);
                });
                var p2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    $scope.getX2($scope.model[option][0][0].id);
                });
                var p3 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    $scope.getX3($scope.model[option][0][0].id);
                });
                var p4 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    $scope.my_data = JSON.parse($scope.model[option][0][0].list);
                });
            // Execute all promises to get the data
            Promise.all([p1,p2,p3,p4]).then(() => {
                debugger;
                // Do some validation and extra formatting on the data we just downloaded
                $scope.update();
            });
        }
    }).then(function(){
        // Display the data to the user
        $scope.move(option, 1, $scope.EDITING);
    });
```

The intended behavior here is:

Get data -> With this data, use id to get data from 4 sources (the 4 promises) -> Once all the data is downloaded, update some references and do some cleaning -> move (which is a method that updates the view and do some other stuff UI related)

But for some reason, the `debugger;` and the `$scope.update();` never get executed. I tried moving these in the same .then as the `$scope.move()` function but then it executes before the data from the Promise.all has been retrieved.

Comment: your p1-p4 promises never finish because you neither call `resolve()` or `reject()` in any of them

Comment: You're never resolving your promises, hence why they never execute the "done" callback of `Promise.all`. Each of your promises (`p1-p4`) should have a `resolve(value)` or `reject(value)` in them.

Comment: Although, I should point out, since you are using angularjs, you should be using the [`$q service`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q). It's the exact same syntax, basically just replace the word "Promise" with "$q" and remove the `new` keyword.

Comment: Assuming those `get…` methods return promises, you should write `var p1 = $scope.getX1($scope.model[option][0][0].id);` etc and omit any `new Promise` calls. If they don't, are they actually asynchronous? Do you even need promises here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never resolve promises 1-4, so the "success callback" to `Promise.all(...).then` never fires. In the callback given to the constructor of each promise, call `resolve` with the data each promise is getting.

```
// ...
var p1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve($scope.getX1($scope.model[option][0][0].id));
});
// ...
```

This is how you "return" data, so to speak, from a Promise. Please see [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) for details.

EDIT: if `$scope.getX1` itself returns a Promise, you can simply assign it to `p1`, ie:

```
var p1 = $scope.getX1($scope.model[option][0][0].id);
```

Comment: I think it's safe to assume that `$scope.getX1` returns an `$http` promise. So you should really chain `.then()` off of `getX1` and put the resolve/reject inside of the `$http` callbacks. Otherwise you are resolving the promise object, not the data being returned by the promise, and it doesn't help the OP.

Comment: You make a good point. I've added an edit to handle this possibility.

Comment: Drop the "if it returns a promise". When it doesn't, wrapping the value in a `Promise.resolve` doesn't help anything either.

Comment: There were 2 things that got me confused. First of all, the `$scope.getX1` was indeed a method intended to return an `$http` promise so I didn't have to create a new Promise... Which got me looking at the `$scope.getX1` function and realize that there was another problem, the function was never returning the promise:

`apiService.getX1(id).then(function (response) { // Do stuff });`

became:

`return apiService.getX1(id).then(function (response) { // Do stuff });`

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Quick tip: if you plan on handling all the responses in your `Promise.all`, I'd hold off on calling `.then` in `getX1`. `.then` does return a promise, so it's not technically broken, but you might be resolving unexpected data if you call `.then` too soon. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then